Constant Wi-Fi Issues and Bluescreens
I’ve been dealing with technical difficulties since I bought my PC in 2019, so this has been going on for a while. It isn’t a regular pattern, and from what I can tell can’t be reproduced on purpose.

Wi-Fi disconnects randomly. There is an audible sound of disconnecting a USB device (likely the Wi-Fi adapter?). Sometimes the Wi-Fi disconnects without the USB disconnect sound. The Wi-Fi tab either shows my PC is disconnected from the router entirely or it shows it’s connected but has no access to internet.

Possible outcomes: 1. Wifi reconnects on its own after X minutes. 2. I have to manually connect to my router again. 3. I have to restart my PC for it to be able to connect again.

Option 3 sometimes leads to a bluescreen after a long time of showing the normal shut down screen of Windows.
PC randomly shows bluescreen and crashes.
PC randomly freezes and has to be manually shut down via power button.
Sudden loud buzzing noise, glitch on my monitors showing a weird mix of bluescreen and whatever was running, followed by a crash.

Bluescreen codes I have encountered and noted so far (It’s possible there are more that I didn’t write down so far):
Code: DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
Code: KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Eventlog shows critical error “Kernel Power 41”
PC specs:
AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor 3.40 GHz
16384MB RAM DDR4 3000MHz
480GB SSD 
1TB SSD (added this year)
MSI Board A320M Pro-E
MSI GTX 1660 Ventus XS OC 6GB
AeroCool RGB Tower
Windows 10 (Version 22H2), OS build 19045.4355
Wi-Fi adapter (German brand): Fritz!Wlan AC 430 MU-MIMO

Does someone have an idea of what’s wrong with my PC? Apologies for any vague descriptions or missing information, I barely have any knowledge when it comes to PCs. Thanks in advance for helping me figure this out!

From Microsoft: "Driver Power State Failure errors are usually caused by a computer or device driver going into sleep mode while you’re still using the device." That source suggests two remedies:

Update the driver for the faulting device. The Fritz! driver is available online, with instructions for installation.
In Power Options, turn off Power Saving.

Press Windows, type power opt, and select the Power Options control panel (CPL).


In the active power plan, shown as selected, click Change plan settings.


In the Edit Plan Settings CPL, click Change advanced power settings.


In the Advanced power settings dialog,

Ensure Wireless Adapter Settings is at Maximum Performance.
Ensure that PCI Express Linked State Power Management is Off.
There may be other power-saving options in that dialog that can also be set off.





However, I'd suggest a third remedy, if those don't work: try another WiFi USB adapter. There are many available for US$8 and up, which would not require an additional driver. Perhaps one might work better on your system. Read reviews before buying.
